# Why is my export bindings for BizTalk using Powershell not working?

Tags: powershell, biztalk

I am trying to automate exporting BizTalk bindings using Powershell. My code gives me this error that "Application true not found" which I had just copied and pasted the application name onto my script, so I am not sure why it is not finding it.  I can't disclose the file path for $bindingfilePath, but this is the file path where I plan to keep the binding file. I also cannot disclose the server name for $server. Below is my code:

```
#make sure the ExplorerOM assembly is loaded
[void][System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadwithPartialName("Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM")

    #Connect to the BizTalk management database
$Catalog = New-Object Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer
$Catalog.ConnectionString = "SERVER=$server; DATABASE=BizTalkMgmtDb; Integrated Security=SSPI"

function bts-application-exportbindings([string]$bindingFilePath, [string]$appName, [boolean]$generateDiffEnvBindings)
{
    $taskParams = ” ExportBindings /Destination:$bindingfilePath$appName.BindingInfo.xml /ApplicationName:$appName ”
    #First version: $p = [diagnostics.process]::start(“BTSTask.exe”, $taskParams)
    Start-Process "BTSTask.exe" $taskParams -Wait

    if($generateDiffEnvBindings)
    {
        $xml = (Get-Content "$bindingfilePath$appName.BindingInfo.xml")

        # QA Binding Info Generation
        $xml.SelectNodes("//Host") | % { 
            $_.NtGroupName = $global:qaNTGroupName
        }
        $xml.Save("$bindingfilePath$appName.QA.BindingInfo.xml")

        # PRD Binding Info Generation
        $xml.SelectNodes("//Host") | % { 
            $_.NtGroupName = $global:prdNTGroupName
        }
        $xml.Save("$bindingfilePath$appName.PRD.BindingInfo.xml")
    }
}


$appName = "Testing_Application"
$bindingfilePath

bts-application-exportbindings $bindingFilePath $True
```

Comment: `bts-application-exportbindings $bindingFilePath $True` -> `bts-application-exportbindings $bindingFilePath $appName $True`

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't give me any errors, but when I go to the file path, I can't find the XML. I copied and pasted the file path on Windows Explorer exactly, so I am not sure why my program is saying it has successfully created a binding file. Is it because I am not calling $Catalog.ConnectionString in the function? I tried it in the parameters and got the same results. @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Check the exit code of `BTSTask.exe`. `$btsTaskProc = Start-Process "BTSTask.exe" $taskParams -Wait -PassThru; $btsTaskProc.ExitCode`